# Why are my select menus beneath their corresponding labels?

Tags: css

[*This link only works in firefox!](http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-1/)

Basically, my dropdown menus are beneath my labels, when I would like them to sit next to their labels, like the keywords section. Does anyone know how I can do this with CSS? I tried floating; that didn't work, and I'm a little wary about positioning.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should share your markup here with associated styles

Comment: Please supply the relevant DOM and CSS code

Comment: `*This link only works in Firefox!`  -  should be `*This link isn't here!`

Comment: Wow sorry, I should be in bed right now. http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-1/

Answer (score 2):

try adding `display: inline-block` to the `.styled-select` and `label` css rules.

Comment: That's not working. I tried `display: inline-block;` with and without `float: left;` and I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Funny, it's working for me in Chrome and Firefox... are you adding display: inline-block to the generic styled-select class?

Comment: @Lindsay.. i translate MassivePenguin answer into Fiddle here and it works fine .. http://jsfiddle.net/MKL9p/

Comment: Yes, this worked. I guess it was my order that wasn't changing it. It's working well now! Thank you. :)

Comment: Any reason why my fields aren't lining up correctly on the left side?